# Multilizer not translating fields on grid

Tags: translation, c++builder

We use multilizer v11 for translation for years. Now the company looks to be defunct not answering communication. We moved the project to another machine for translation and noticed this: [image]

The grid headings some of them are translated while others are not. Product Description for instance, I see it translated in the project file.[image]

Help on this appreciated.

Comment: Multilizer is dead. It has been for many years. The newest build is more than 6 years old. I recommend to switch to another localization tool such as
https://www.soluling.com
Soluling is written in Delphi and it support Delphi away better than Multilizer
https://www.soluling.com/Help/Delphi/Index.htm

Comment: Soluling can import your exiting translation. First use Multilizer to create the localized files (localized EXs or localized resource DLL). Then just create a new Soluling project containing the same Delphi generated EXE file. Soluling find the localized EXEs/DLLs and import the translations. You won't loose any translations.

Comment: You will also get a discount because you are an exiting Multilizer customer.

Comment: One more thing. Multilizer's company, Rex Partner Oy, is in big trouble. You can see here how badly they are doing financially.
https://www.finder.fi/Sovellukset+ja+ohjelmistot/Rex+Partners+Oy/Espoo/yhteystiedot/248932

Comment: @Jaska Thank you for your response. For our newer version, we decided not to go with Multilizer. This is an older version we are still supporting. Maybe Soluling is the way to go. Thanks.